# Android - share facebook only white screen

Tags: facebook, button, hyperlink, sdk, share

i create share facebook button, i've follow step by step in tutorial developer facebook, but when i try to share link, after login only white screen. i'm using sdk 4.7

[image]

and this is my code :

```
ShareButton tosharefb = (ShareButton) findViewById(R.id.sharefb);
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aT6kf9rN23Y"))
        .build();
tosharefb.setShareContent(content);
```

Comment: Are you trying this on a website, or a **offline** file? The latter will not work, as it can't access FB's SDK.

Comment: i trying share link not from youtube working but when link from youtube only white screen

Comment: Does this only happen with this YouTube video? Do other YouTube video's work?

Comment: no, all video link not work